# Adicionar 2 ou mais email em txt usando como separador a ','

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde,

Como posso fazer para adicionar 2 ou mais E-mails no mesmo campo usando um separador ',' pelo evento blur do jQuery?
O código já está montando, porém preciso modificar para que ele aceita o novo registro sem sobrepor o outro. E, claro o validador de Email aceitar o mesmo.

Obs. O código é desenvolvido em ASP.NET e, já funciona normal, só preciso de uma orientação para fazer essa modificação. A baixo está o código do qual preciso alterar.

Perdoai pela simplicidade da solicitação e obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa tarde, no método validar e-mail poderia ser utilizado um vetor de e-mails para fazer a validação e poderia utilizar o 

var[] emails = email.split(',')

e criar um loop dentro do método para validar todos ....